# The correct syntax of this for loop statement

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class, something like:

```
class A : std::queue<double>
{
  [...]

  void foo();
};
```

Inside foo() I want to iterate through its elements, but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

I assumed it would be something like: `for(auto elem : *this) {}` but that doesn't work (a long list of compiler errors). What is the correct syntax?

Comment: [One should not inherit from standard containers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806173/subclass-inherit-standard-containers). Also, [Queue does not store it's values in order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893530/iterate-through-queue-of-objects-in-order)

Comment: @MooingDuck That second link is for Java. Just sayin'... ;)

Comment: Actually neither of @MooingDuck's links are relevant.  `std::queue` is not `java.util.Queue`, and `std::queue` is not a container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `queue` can not be iterated directly, however it has a protected member [`c`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) which is the underlying container. Hence this should work for your case:

```
for( auto elem : c ) { ... }
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/163046474eff909c)