# Queue is not adding object properly

Tags: java, queue

I am having some issues, like in the title, with adding objects to a queue in java. I am trying to write some code that simulates a toll booth, cars, and a queue. Below is the code.

```
    //Below is creating and naming objects and variables
    int numberOfCars, numberOfTollbooths; 
    double tollboothTotalServiceTime = 0, tollboothAverageServiceTime = 0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    ExpRandom random = new ExpRandom(13);
    Queue<Car> carQueue = new LinkedList<Car>();

    //Asks the user how many cars need to be created for this simulation
    System.out.print("How many cars do you want to simulate? ");
    numberOfCars = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.next());

    for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfCars; i++)
    {
        carQueue.add(new Car(i, Increasing.increasingNumber()/10));
        System.out.println("Car queue: [" + carQueue.poll() + "]");
    }
```

Output:

```
#1 arrived at time 1.
Car queue: [#1]
#2 arrived at time 2.
Car queue: [#2]
#3 arrived at time 4.
Car queue: [#3]
#4 arrived at time 18.
Car queue: [#4]
#5 arrived at time 33.
Car queue: [#5]
#6 arrived at time 38.
Car queue: [#6]
#7 arrived at time 42.
Car queue: [#7]
#8 arrived at time 47.
Car queue: [#8]
#9 arrived at time 48.
Car queue: [#9]
#10 arrived at time 52.
Car queue: [#10]
#11 arrived at time 53.
Car queue: [#11]
#12 arrived at time 58.
Car queue: [#12]
```

how can i see the whole carQueue once all the cars are added? something like Car queue: [1,2,3,4...]

Comment: And what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`poll` removes the head](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) of the queue, use `peek` instead.

```
System.out.println("Car queue: [" + carQueue.peek() + "]");
```

Comment: how can i view the whole queue? when i added all the objects?

Comment: @user1803052 [use a for each](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893530/iterate-through-queue-of-objects-in-order).